# Mysql Cluster data ndoe can not start to connecto management node

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

Now, every config is ok , but when I use

> ./ndbd --initial

on data node , it will ouput log :

**ndb_mgm :**

> Forced node shutdown completed. Occured during startphase 0. Caused by error 2350: 'Invalid configuration received from Management Server(Configuration error). Permanent error, external action needed'.

**ndbd :**

> - 2018-05-10 13:54:43 [ndbd] INFO     -- Angel pid: 14533 started child: 14534
> - 2018-05-10 13:54:43 [ndbd] INFO     -- Initial start of data node, ignoring any info on disk
> - 2018-05-10 13:54:43 [ndbd] INFO     -- Configuration fetched from '172.19.16.170:1186', generation: 1
> - 2018-05-10 13:54:43 [ndbd] INFO     -- Changing directory to '/var/lib/mysql-cluster'
> - 2018-05-10 13:54:43 [ndbd] INFO     -- Invalid configuration fetched
> - 2018-05-10 13:54:43 [ndbd] INFO     -- ConfigParam: 113 not found
> - 2018-05-10 13:54:43 [ndbd] INFO     -- Error handler shutting down system
> - 2018-05-10 13:54:43 [ndbd] INFO     -- Error handler shutdown completed - exiting
> - 2018-05-10 13:54:43 [ndbd] ALERT    -- Node 2: Forced node shutdown completed. Occured during startphase 0. Caused by error 2350: 'Invalid configuration received from Management Server(Configuration error). Permanent error, external action needed'.

Now, the ndbd log tell me , it fetch configuration from server error, but I dont know where is the error.

Thsi is my management node configuration :

> - [ndbd default]
> - NoOfReplicas= 1
> - [mysqld  default]
> - [ndb_mgmd default]
> - [tcp default]
> - [ndb_mgmd]
> - HostName= 172.19.16.170
> - [ndbd]
> - NodeId=2
> - HostName= 172.19.16.166
> - DataDir= /var/lib/mysql-cluster
> - [ndbd]
> - NodeId=3
> - HostName= 172.19.16.167
> - DataDir= /var/lib/mysql-cluster
> - [mysqld]
> - [mysqld]
> - [mysqld]

Answer (score 0):

This is an upgrade issue. The error only occurs in ndbd up to
version 7.5. But it is only the ndb_mgmd from version 7.6 that
can set IndexMemory to 0. ConfigParam: 113 is IndexMemory which
is deprecated in 7.6. So probably you are running a ndb_mgmd from
version 7.6 and ndbd from version 7.5.